# how to push first object values in to array using FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to push first object only into array but it's adding all the objects. I have attached the screen shot. I have three fields first is firstname and last name street. I need to show only first object value. but it's showing all the data. How to display first one object, it having multiple objectives also?
Below is the CODE URL

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup2-first?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the mapper, and only push first element

```
   let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
      formArr.push(fb.group({
        firstname: this.users[0].firstname,
        lastname: this.users[0].lastname,
        street: this.users[0].street
      }))
```